# how to make a web services in android and connect it to a website to fetch the data

Tags: java, android, web-services

i am going to create an android application for the website of my own academy.so i have created the application in android but now do not know how to create a web services that will fetch the data from a website??

i am totally new in webservice and java programming. My question is where should i start to learn this , i tried to search some example to create webservice in java but i was not able to get any good tutorial.

It would be appreciated, if any body help me understand the flow.

Thanks..

Comment: Your android app is not a web service, it is a web client. Use an HTTP client (jdk's or Apache's or any other) to send HTTP request to your school's website.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use CORS to fetch datasets from a website, as your android device does not run a web application, but run an activity which runs a webview to ping a website.   You can use the java back end to fetch data as well, using a similar CORS or socketing approach.

That way, you can do stuff via javascript and via Java.

Also, using something like Cordova will link both JS and Java together.

Keep in mind, for your application that not all people have unlimited Data, so try to minimize the fetched datasets as much as you can.   As a user, you might not know it but could mighht fetch 1 meg, but you might end up doing it like 50 times, which really chews up information.

Comment: hey, I know it's a really old post, but could you reccomend a book, or a tutorial to learn how to do these things you described?

Comment: Could you be more specific?   Are you primarily wanting to learn how to use javascript to fetch information from servers, or bridge the Javascript front end with Java backend?